# Asp.Net Mvc - Is it safe to store things in a static variable that's reinitialized in Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, appdomain

I have some general non-critical information on the current deployment that is collected inside `Application_Start` and is currently stored in a public static readonly string.

It's just a small string so I'm not worried about memory usage or anything.

Does this work from the point of view of Application Domain recycling? Will there ever be a scenario where the values inside my static will simply disappear and not be reinitialized?

Comment: If an exception prevents the value from being properly populated (say, you're reading it from a config file and the config file is corrupt), then the first request to the application will show the error (I think?) but all subsequent requests will proceed with the value as null.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs before the variable is populated and the exception is swallowed then the string will be null.

Comment: Well...yeah...that applies any time you're assigning a variable. The question is specifically about static variables, initialization, and application recycling